# Добавления знака "переноса строки" в XML строку на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, строки

Необходимо отредактировать XML файл записанный в одну строку, путем добавления туда знака переноса строки. Напи санный мною код ниже:

```
def strClear():
    s = "maa<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows - 1251' ?><ROOT><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>1</ID><Text>Арбитр подсоединен</Text><Time>13178646355061.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>0</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>2</ID><Text>нет сетевого соединения</Text><Time>13178646374521.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>3</ID><Text>Арбитр отсоединен</Text><Time>1317864637</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>8</ID><Text>Арбитр подсоединен</Text><Time>13178646383266.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>1</Actual><ID>7</ID><Text>нет сетевого соединения</Text><Time>131786</Time></elem></ROOT>"
    number_first = s.find('<')  # Поиск "<", как точка отсчета
    s = s[number_first:]  # Делаем срез от точки отсчета до конца строки
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[number_first + i] == '>' and s[number_first + i + 1] == '<':
            # Если совпадает условие, то после знака ">" добавляем перенос строки
            s = s.replace(s[number_first + i], s[number_first + i] + '\n')
        i = i + 1
    print(number_first)
    print(len(s))
    print(s)





strClear()
```

Проблема заключается в том, что перенос добавляется сразу после знака ">", даже если после него стоит буква или цифра. Хотя по условию чтобы можно было добавить знак переноса "\n" необходимо чтобы следующим после ">" был "<". Грешу на то, что где-то, что-то упустил или не правильно написал. 
В теории должно быть так:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows - 1251' ?>
<ROOT>
<elem>
<Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged>
<Active>0</Active>
<Actual>0</Actual>
<ID>1</ID>
<Text>Арбитр подсоединен</Text>
```

А по факту получается так:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows - 1251' ?>
<ROOT>
<elem>
<Acknowledged>
1</Acknowledged>
<Active>
0</Active>
<Actual>
0</Actual>
<ID>
1</ID>
<Text>
Арбитр подсоединен</Text>
```

:-(

Comment: И зачем вам это? Оо

Comment: Для того чтобы в дальнейшем "распарсить" эти XML данные. Эту строку я "снимаю" с TCP порта. Туда XML данные приходят именно в видке строки без знаков перевода строки.

Comment: я вам решение покажу, но не понимаю зачем вам это... то что вы хотите называется pretty-xml, там еще отступы добавляются. Да и слово парсить вы неудачное написали, парсерам на отсутствие переносов пофиг, я так понимаю, это чтобы вам удобно было видеть. Насчет pretty-xml, вот пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c3ded4038659995a6673b96427944181be9b6f16/pretty_xml/pretty_xml.py

Comment: хмм..Я понял. Мне думал, что важно чтобы в XML файле были знаки "переноса строки". Ну а как если не "парсить" ?))) мне же нужно будет потои из определенных элементов выделить текст, и дальше с ним работать. Короче я еще профан в программировании и в python в частности поэтому не претендую на правдивость того, что говорю))

Comment: Для работы с xml лучше использовать специализированные библиотеки, например lxml и BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем регулярку, которая заменит закрывающий тег на него же и добавит `\n`:

```
import re
new_text = re.sub(r'(</.+?>)', r'\1\n', s)
print(new_text)
```

Результат:

```
maa<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows - 1251' ?><ROOT><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged>
<Active>0</Active>
<Actual>0</Actual>
<ID>1</ID>
<Text>Арбитр подсоединен</Text>
<Time>13178646355061.0000000000000</Time>
</elem>
<elem><Acknowledged>0</Acknowledged>
<Active>0</Active>
<Actual>0</Actual>
<ID>2</ID>
<Text>нет сетевого соединения</Text>
<Time>13178646374521.0000000000000</Time>
</elem>
<elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged>
<Active>0</Active>
<Actual>0</Actual>
<ID>3</ID>
<Text>Арбитр отсоединен</Text>
<Time>1317864637</Time>
</elem>
<elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged>
<Active>0</Active>
<Actual>0</Actual>
<ID>8</ID>
<Text>Арбитр подсоединен</Text>
<Time>13178646383266.0000000000000</Time>
</elem>
<elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged>
<Active>0</Active>
<Actual>1</Actual>
<ID>7</ID>
<Text>нет сетевого соединения</Text>
<Time>131786</Time>
</elem>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Век живи - век учись! Это про меня))  Я не знал про эту библиотеку(

Comment: Пожалуйста :) регулярки это отдельная и большая (больная) тема, но как я и писал под вашим вопросом, для работы с xml лучше использовать специальные библиотеки (парсеры), и `re` (регулярные выражения) нужно осторожно с xml/html использовать -- парсеры намного лучше справятся